# Searching IntelliJ project does not yield expected results (not a duplicate, I looked)

Tags: android-studio, ide, intellij-14

I am searching for a string within my Golang project within Intellij. From the 'project' side bar I right click on the project name and select 'Find in Files...' which is the same as CMD + Shift + F, I am working of a Mac computer. In the search window, as a test, I type a simple string and get 0 results. Meanwhile I am staring at the string I am searching for in the code. Am I using the search engine incorrectly? Is my IDE broken?
I apologize if this issue has been addressed and resolved.